# Assertion failure when running make

Tags: c++, c, assert

I get this assertion failure even though I do not think I should.
After I run I get an assertion failed message.
Any idea on what should I do?

```
#include <assert.h>

/**
 * Increment integer.
 *
 * @param j The integer to increment.
 *
 * @return The result of j incremented.
 */
int16_t increment(int16_t j) {
    return ++j;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int n_increments = 100000; // Increment 100000 times.

    int16_t old_value = 0;
    int16_t new_value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_increments; ++i) {
        new_value = increment(old_value);
        printf("%i",(new_value == (old_value + 1)));
        assert(new_value == (old_value + 1));
        old_value = new_value;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's to be expected when you use a 16-bit integer and try to loop to 100000. You'll fail as soon as you reach 2^15.

Comment: wont it just loop around?

Comment: When it does, `new_value == -32768` and `old_value == 32767`, so `new_value == old_value + 1` is not true.

Comment: well i want to upvote you, so can you write this as an answer ?

Comment: Thanks but I don't care about votes, happy to help.

Comment: To see what Passerby is saying you could add a `printf` to your loop

Comment: Note that integer overflow on a signed value is undefined behavior, so the entire program is considered invalid (according to the C++ spec).  If you want well-defined behavior on overflow, use unsigned integer types instead.

Comment: This has nothing to do with makefiles. Please edit your question to replace "_After I run make_" by "_After I execute_" and remove the `makefile` tag.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet i just did, thank you guys